# What do "Non-Power-Of-Two Textures" mean?

Tags: c++, opengl

What do "Non-Power-Of-Two Textures" mean? I read [this tutorial](http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/OpenGL/08_non_power_of_2_textures/index.php) and I meet some binaries operations("<<", ">>", "^", "~"), but I don't understand what they are doing.
For example following code:

```
GLuint LTexture::powerOfTwo(GLuint num)
{
    if (num != 0)
    {
        num--;
        num |= (num >> 1); //Or first 2 bits
        num |= (num >> 2); //Or next 2 bits
        num |= (num >> 4); //Or next 4 bits
        num |= (num >> 8); //Or next 8 bits
        num |= (num >> 16); //Or next 16 bits
        num++;
    }
    return num;
}
```

I very want to understand this operations. As well, I read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/czs2584d.aspx). Very short article. I want to see examples of using, but I not found. I did the test:

```
int a = 5;
a <<= 1; //a = 10
a = 5;
a <<= 2; //a = 20
a = 5;
a <<= 3; //a = 40
```

Okay, this like multiply on two, but

```
int a = 5;
a >>= 1; // a = 2 Whaat??
```

Comment: `a >>= 1;` is division by two (2 fits two times into 5)

Comment: `<<` and `>>` are explained in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_shift#Bit_shifts .

Comment: I recommend you get familiar with the binary system first, otherwise you won't be able to understand how these operators work.

Comment: A power of two texture is one whose dimensions are powers of two. For example, a texture that is 417x316 pixels is not a power of two texture. But one that is 256x256 (or 512x1024) is.

Answer (score 0):

As said in http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/OpenGL/08_non_power_of_2_textures/index.php
`powerOfTwo` will take the argument and find nearest number that is power of two.

```
 GLuint powerOfTwo( GLuint num );
    /*
    Pre Condition:
     -None
    Post Condition:
     -Returns nearest power of two integer that is greater
    Side Effects:
     -None
    */
```

Let's test:

num=60 (decimal) and its binary is 111100

```
    num--;                                   .. 59  111011
    num |= (num >> 1); //Or first 2 bits     011101 | 111011 = 111111
    num |= (num >> 2); //Or next 2 bits      001111 | 111111 = 111111
    num |= (num >> 4); //Or next 4 bits      000011 | 111111 = 111111
    num |= (num >> 8); //Or next 8 bits      000000 | 111111 = 111111
    num |= (num >> 16); //Or next 16 bits    000000 | 111111 = 111111
    num++;                                   ..63+1 = 64
```

output 64.

For num=5: num-1 =4 (binary 0100), after all `num |= (num >> N)` it will be 0111 or 7 decimal). Then num+1 is equal to 8.

Answer (score 0):

In C++, the `<<=` is the "left binary shift" assignment operator; the operand on the left is treated as a binary number, the bits are moved to the left, and zero bits are inserted on the right.

The `>>=` is the right binary shift; bits are moved to the right and "fall off" the right end, so it's like a division by 2 (for each bit) but with truncation. For negative signed integers, by the way, additional 1 bits are shifted in at the left end ("arithmetic right shift"), which may be surprising; for positive signed integers, or unsigned integers, 0 bits are shifted in at the left ("logical right shift").

"Powers of two" are the numbers created by successive doublings of 1: 2, 4, 8, 16, 32… Most graphics hardware prefers to work with texture maps which are powers of two in size.

Answer (score 0):

As you should know the data in our computers is represented in the binary system, in which digits are either a 1 or a 0.
So for example number 10 decimal = `1010` binary. (1*2^3 + 0*2^2 + 1*2^1 + 0*2^0).

Let's go to the operations now.

Binary | OR means that wherever you have at least one 1 the output will be 1.

```
  1010
| 0100
------
  1110
```

~ NOT means negation i.e. all 0s become 1s and all 1s become 0s.

```
~ 1010
------
  0101
```

^ XOR means you turn a pair of 1 and 0 into a 1. All other combinations leave a 0 as output.

```
  1010
^ 0110
------
  1100
```

Bit shift.

`N >> x` means we "slide" our number N, x bits to the right.

```
1010 >> 1 = 0101(0) // zero in the brackets is dropped,
                       since it goes out of the representation = 0101
1001 >> 1 = 0100(1) // (1) is dropped = 0100
```

<< behaves the same way, just the opposite direction.

```
1000 << 1 = 0001
```

Since in binary system numbers are represented as powers of 2, shifting a bit one or the other direction will result in multiplying or dividing by 2.

Answer (score 0):

Let num = 36. First subtract 1, giving 35. In binary, this is 100011.

Right shift by 1 position gives 10001 (the rightmost digit disappears). Bitwise Or'ed with num gives:

```
 100011
  10001
-------
 110011
```

Note that this ensures two 1's on the left.

Now right shift by 2 positions, giving 1100. Bitwise Or:

```
 110011
   1100
-------
 111111
```

This ensures four 1's on the left.

And so on, until the value is completely filled with 1's from the leftmost.

Add 1 and you get 1000000, a power of 2.

This procedure always generates a power of two, and you can check that it is just above the initial value of num.